# webrtc : how to avoid PermissionDenied security error?

Tags: webrtc

I am using nodejs with webrtc for a simple 1to1 chat.

It works great when content is server through nodejs:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1234/
```

works fine.

My idea was to use apache so I try to access it thorugh

```
http://127.0.0.1/webrtc/
```

and I got this error in my chrome logs:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError

constraintName: ""

message: ""

**name: "PermissionDeniedError"**

__proto__: NavigatorUserMediaError

constructor: function NavigatorUserMediaError() { [native code] }

__proto__: Object
```

Do you have an idea why I cannot run it within apache and gives me that nasty PermissionDeniedError ?

**It seems the browser may be treating the different ports as different origins and throwing a PermissionDenied security error.**

Any idea how to avoid that ?

Comment: Can you paste some code?